# How to setup a multi-department form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I"m hoping there is a way to do this.  I'm creating a webpage in HTML5 and JavaScript that three different departments will use in order to log calls.  I have three buttons one for each department.  I was able to make it load a blank page, then when a button is clicked it displays the HTML form for that specific department.  I used code here I found on another question.

The issue I'm running into is when the form is submitted, it switches the page back to the blank default.  How do I make it keep the previous department form that was last used?

In other words if department 1 is displayed and the user clicks submit, it reloads department 1, if they are using department 2 form and they click submit, it reloads department 2 form, etc for department 3.

Right now they have to reclick their department to reload the form.  I tried using things like onsubmit, or on click to do so but it won't trigger.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="department">
   <input type="button" class="DeptTitle" value="Department 1" onClick="return changeDept1()" />
   <input type="button" class="DeptTitle" value="Department 2" onClick="return changeDept2()" />
   <input type="button" class="DeptTitle" value="Department3" onClick="return changeDept3()" />
</div>
<div class="body" id="default"></div>
<div class="body" id="Dept1"><form id="calllog" action="" method="post"><input type="Submit" value="Submit" /></form></div>
<div class="body" id="Dept2"><form id="calllog" action="" method="post"><input type="Submit" value="Submit" /></form></div>
<div class="body" id="Dept3"><form id="calllog" action="" method="post"><input type="Submit" value="Submit" /></form></div>
```

Here is my CSS that I used to hide and show the departments

```
/* Different Departments, hides all but default */

#default {display: block;}
#Dept1 {display: none;}
#Dept2 {display: none;}
#Dept3 {display: none;}
```

Lastly here is the JavaScript code that I use from another answer here to switch between the different forms.

```
function changeDept1() {
document.getElementById('default').style.display = "none"; // hide default div tag
document.getElementById('Dept1').style.display = "block"; // show Dept1 Form div tag
document.getElementById('Dept2').style.display = "none"; // hide Dept2 Form div tag
document.getElementById('Dept3').style.display = "none"; // hide Dept3 div tag
}

function changeDept2() {
document.getElementById('default').style.display = "none"; // hide default div tag
document.getElementById('Dept1').style.display = "none"; // hide Dept1 Form div tag
document.getElementById('Dept2').style.display = "block"; // show Dept2 Form div tag
document.getElementById('Dept3').style.display = "none"; // hide Dept3 div tag
}

function changeDept3() {
document.getElementById('default').style.display = "none"; // hide default div tag
document.getElementById('Dept1').style.display = "none"; // hide Dept1 Form div tag
document.getElementById('Dept2').style.display = "none"; // hide Dept2 Form div tag
document.getElementById('Dept3').style.display = "block"; // show Dept3 div tag
}
```

The above works to change between forms, just that it won't keep it once the form submits.  I tried adding onsubmit to both the submit button and the form itself to get it to redisplay the form.  The script I tried to use is here:

```
function showDept1 () {
document.getElementById('Dept1').style.display = "block"; // show Dept1 Form div tag
}
```

I was only testing with the first department as a test to keep it from disappearing when submitted.

Also is there a way to make the form reset everytime it's switched out.  If I start to fill out one form, then switch to another department then back again, the first form is still filled out.  Not sure if these two issues would be related.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the JavaScript and just use named anchors.

For example, I have a CodePen with the bare minimum code you will need: http://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/OPgmPe

If you want to see it in action, here it is showing each of the three options (you can obviously tweak this to use elements other than a list):

- http://s.codepen.io/aardrian/debug/OPgmPe#Expando1
- http://s.codepen.io/aardrian/debug/OPgmPe#Expando2
- http://s.codepen.io/aardrian/debug/OPgmPe#Expando3

You can then just post each form (since you already have three `<form>` elements) to the URL with the appropriate named anchor, which are basically the URLs above.

There is no JavaScript.

The entirety of the CSS:

```
.expando {
  display: none;
}

.expando:target {
  display: block;
}
```

The entirety of the HTML (with the content):

```
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Expando1">The Tick</a>
      <ul class="expando" id="Expando1">
        <li>Has superhuman strength and mass;</li>
        <li>Is nigh-invulnerable; </li>
        <li>Has powers that increase as the situation becomes more dramatic;</li>
        <li>Does not seem to require oxygen;</li>
        <li>Cannot keep his balance if his antennae are removed.</li>
      </ul>    
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Expando2">Sewer Urchin</a>
      <ul class="expando" id="Expando2">
        <li>Has slime &amp; stench secreting spikes on his suit enable him to stick on any surface;</li>
        <li>Is equipped with lemon grenades, butter shooters, bars of soap and other various apparel to aid him in his underground endeavors; </li>
        <li>Has an oxygen tank and mask which enable him to breath in the thickest of sewer sludge;</li>
        <li>Has a submarine that he garbage-picked.</li>
      </ul>    
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Expando3">Arthur</a>
      <ul class="expando" id="Expando3">
        <li>Has a suit that enables wobbly flight;</li>
        <li>Has an accounting background.</li>
      </ul>    
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Ok I tested it and the code is cleaner however the issue still remains.  When I hit submit to submit the form, it disappears off the page.  I need the form to submit but stay on the page without having to click on the department link every time.  How can I make the form stay on the screen?

Comment: AJAX, or essentially a JavaScript-only submission allows you to submit a form without a page refresh. However, I thought your objective was to put a user back on the same view of the page after submitting. Preventing a page refresh is a whole different process.

Comment: Well correct yes I don't want them to leave the page, but I am also look for the same form that was just submitted to reappear again so they can fill out another call log.

Comment: Did you post the form to the URL with the named anchor? I forked the pen and added a form so you can see it in action. [Editable pen](http://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/GqxjqP?editors=1000), and the [same pen sans editor](http://s.codepen.io/aardrian/debug/GqxjqP) that you can post like mad.

Comment: Ok that worked, I added the anchor #Dept1, #Dept2, #Dept3 to the action in each form so that it would repost the form.  How would this work though since each form is going to post and submit the data to an excel file?  Would the posting to the excel file be in the submit button and I leave the anchor in the form action or can I combine the two in the form field?

Comment: I suspect you are not posting *directly* to an Excel file. You probably have a back-end process doing that work. You can just use the text of the button or a hidden field (like the one I stuffed in there to show the URL change) to pass along to the back-end process which one you submitted.

Comment: Perfect thank you.  Correct with the number of people that will be using it, all the posting is handled back end.  I just wanted to make sure it wouldn't interfere with the submission.  I didn't use a hidden field like you have, I just added the it as a tag such as "action="CallLog.html#Dept1" in each form changing the value after the # for each one